# Is it haram to think how other people would react to something you did?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

Assalamualaikum, i could actually get glasses for my eyes, so i was thinking if i did got glasses, how other people would react to it? Is this haram?

Answer (score 0):

No ; like i'ts baselless assumption; maybe having desire while thinking about  womens is haram ; due to the lust in the heart based on this hadith

An-Nawawi  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him commented on the hadeeth, saying, “The hadeeth means that it has been decreed that each and every person shall inevitably commit a share of adultery; some will commit actual physical fornication by engaging in unlawful sexual intercourse, and others will commit fornication only in a figurative sense by means of lustful gazes ... or by mere sinful thoughts harbored within their hearts. All of these acts are considered figurative forms of fornication...” [Sharh Saheeh Muslim]

Al-Mulla ʻAli Al-Qaari  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him wrote, “It is deduced from the hadeeth that if sinful wishing settles in the heart and the person insists upon it and does not repel it, it is called fornication. It is a sin and it deserves punishment, even if he does not act upon it.” [Mirqaat Al-Mafateeh Sharh Mishkaat Al-Masaabeeh]